Unable to resolve module expo-router/entry.js when run comand `npx expo run:android --variant release`
Yesterday I upgraded expo 51 to expo 52 and everything is working correctly when I run npx expo start and I test my app in expo go, but when I try to create a local build with npx expo run:android --variant release I get the next error:
npx expo run:android --variant release
› Opening emulator Pixel_3a_API_35
› Building app...
Starting Metro Bundler
warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)
Error: Unable to resolve module ./D:/Repositorios/listtendance/node_modules/expo-router/entry.js from D:\Repositorios\listtendance/.:

None of these files exist:
  * D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js(.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.android.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.android.css|.native.css|.css|.android.css|.native.css|.css)
  * D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js
Error: Unable to resolve module ./D:/Repositorios/listtendance/node_modules/expo-router/entry.js from D:\Repositorios\listtendance/.:

None of these files exist:
  * D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js(.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.android.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.android.css|.native.css|.css|.android.css|.native.css|.css)
  * D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:112:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:235:43)
    at D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:160:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1104:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.resolveRelativePathAsync (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\start\server\metro\MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:1677:12)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.metroLoadModuleContents (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\start\server\metro\MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:506:35)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.legacySinglePageExportBundleAsync (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\start\server\metro\MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:809:20)
    at exportEmbedBundleAndAssetsAsync (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\export\embed\exportEmbedAsync.ts:193:21)
    at exportEmbedInternalAsync (D:\Repositorios\listtendance\node_modules\@expo\cli\src\export\embed\exportEmbedAsync.ts:125:37)


I have already tried to removing node_modules and run npm install, npx expo install --fix, but none of these commands work,I have also tried running npx expo-doctor, npx expo start --clear and clear the cache of the node_modules, but I get none results. Before the upgrade I had no problems creating a build. I have already tried downgrading but it seems my project uses expo 52 even when I change the expo version in package.json
This is my metro.config.js:

const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const { withNativeWind } = require("nativewind/metro");

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = withNativeWind(config, { input: "./global.css" });

babel.config.js

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo", { jsxImportSource: "nativewind" }], "nativewind/babel"
    ],
   };
};



To get the answer to your question, click the link and read through the responses : [expo-51] Android app unable to resolve module expo-router/entry inside monorepo (new arch enabled or not) -> https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/28775

@PratikPrakashBindage I have already tried changing main to index.ts in package.json and using EXPO_USE_METRO_WORKSPACE_ROOT=1 in a .env but it does not work
